# Efficient file format to store nested objects

Tags: python

I am working on a python project where I have nested objects. I know the structure of each entity. I am looking for a way to save it.

**Here is a very simple example:**

A User always have:

- an id (int)
- a name: (string)
- a list of items (0, 1 or many)

An item always have:

- a name (str)
- a price (int)

```
to_save_data = [
    { 'id': 8, 'name': 'Alice', 'items': [ { 'name': 'Sword', 'price': 10 } ] },
    { 'id': 23, 'name': 'Bob', 'items': [ { 'name': 'Axe', 'price': 4 }, { 'name': 'Shield', 'price': 33 } ] },
    { 'id': 57, 'name': 'Charlie', 'items': [] },
]
```

I need to store the data with following constrainst:

- All in one file, one line should correspond to one user
- I can read / write line by line. I can add a line at the end of file (without reading all and rewriting all)
- values are not encoded (like a csv file for instance but not like a pickle file)
- efficient in terms of space.

I started with JSON but it is not efficient in terms of space because the name of each field is repated and written for each line.
In this example, words "id", "name" and "items" are written 3 times (if I had 1B users, it would be written 1B times, same problem for items).

**I am looking for something that would look like this for instance:**

A header on the first line that describes the data-structure. then:

```
8, 'Alice', [ ('Sword', 10) ]
23, 'Bob', [ ('Axe', 4), ('Shield', 33) ]
57, 'Charlie', []
```

I could implement it but it would take time and I feel I would reinvent the wheel.

**Is there an existing file-format and python module to handle that ?**

Comment: Your constraints are at odds with each other.  Human readable and space efficient won't play well together.

Comment: You could write [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and [compress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/archiving.html) that. That keeps data size low, and the format is flexible to changes, especially if you include meta data like a version number. Decompress, and you have it human readable again. Reading / writing single lines requires (de)compressing the whole file, though. I'd still prefer this over inventing my own format (which others won't understand) and having to write my own parser for it.

Comment: The size requirement smells a bit of premature optimization. If you really have billions of records, you should probably look at a database, not inventing your own file format.

Comment: @MarkRansom What I mean by human readable is: values are written as they are. For instance in a csv file, If I open the csv, I can read values. In a Pickle file for instance i can not read the values of a line

Comment: @Robert I actually have a 1 billion records. What I need to do is store them. Then an algorithm will have to pass line by line to process each line (in the same order as they were saved). A db would slow down a lot the process (i have multiple entities so for each line I would have to perform multiple sql requests or I could batch but I still need to perform multiple sql queries / joins which is much slower than just reading a file line by line).

Comment: No need for multiple SQL queries, a single query can return multiple results (items).

Comment: @MarkRansom If all the data can not fit in memory you can not just do 1 sql query

Comment: People do it every day, I don't understand what your concern is.

Comment: @VinceM you mentioned CSV. Why don't you choose it? Make different files with primary keys like in a database, e.g. people, items and etc., write them and compress with something like 7-zip or RAR. This way it can be loaded quite fast in pandas and can be viewed within zip programs by simply double clicking on a file.

Comment: @MarkRansom The real data is: I have blocks. A block has transactions (and other fields related to block). A transaction has Transfers (and other fields related to transfers). 
I can not store in  memory more than 1M Block. I have 1B Block.
I need to process blocks in a specific order.
So the idea would be: repeat 1k times an sql query with a limit of 1M with 2 joins.
I think it would be much slower than a file i could just read line by line.

Comment: @VinceM depends, analytical databases like Vertica or Clickhouse are quite fast on joins for consecutive data

Comment: @DiMithras 
I have 1Billion entity A
Each entity A has on average 1 entity B
Each entity B has on average 1 entity C

So If I create 3 files: A.csv B.csv, C.csv. I can not just read them with pandas: 1st because it is too big, i can not read all. 2nd because if I read by batch, I need to implement a complex logic to know where to start/end the reading of file B and C.

For instance if I read the first 1k lines of file A. Where should I end the reading of file B to get all B entity related to this first 1k A entities ? same for C ?

Comment: @VinceM yeah, CSV won't work. But that's what analytical DBs are meant for.

Comment: @DiMithras Ok, thank you. I did not know about this kind of DB. I will look at it. I was just hopping there was a file format for this kind of saving. It does not look very hard (I was considering implementing it). But if it does not exist I will look for DB solutions. (or i will try to implement it...)

Comment: @VinceM nothing I'm aware of like others who commented. Your case with headers is a perfect case for compression. While using DBs you also get indexing, different methods and other cool stuff that might be helpful. Benchmarks can be seen [here](https://benchmark.clickhouse.com/), column-oriented databases are really fast.

Comment: Why not create a table with a int column, varchar column, and variant column? For constraints put it on the int column and compress for "efficient in terms of space"